# How do I find and replace all non-finite numbers in an Eigen::Array object?

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I have an array filled with doubles:

```
Eigen::Array<double,m,n> myarray;
```

Now I want to replace any elements of `myarray` which are not finite with the number `0.0` How would I do this?

I was thinking of multiplying it by an array of values with zeros where I find infinity, like this:

```
myarray *= myarray.cwiseEqual(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) == 0.0;
```

And doing this for every invalid type. But this is really messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12):

Here's one easy way to do it:

```
myarray = myarray.unaryExpr([](double v) { return std::isfinite(v)? v : 0.0; });
```

Source:
[[http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7]](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7%5d)

Comment: oh, minCoeff() returns NAN only on debug. Odd Eigen behavior.